# Angular run function and then apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am running a big task in a controller in angular and i have some watchers that could be triggered in between the execution of the code and due to performance improving i don't want this to happen.

How could I avoid angular triggering some watcher while the code is running? Is this already handled inside the Angular magic? Could this be solved with $q, or there is a better way to do it?

Example:

```
$scope.variableThatKeepsChanging = {};

function someVeryLongFuntion(){
  var someVar = variableThatKeepsChanging;
  (...);
}

$scope.clickedFn = function () {
  //Here should start someVeryLongFuntion()
  someVeryLongFuntion();
  //Only now should be run the $apply() function of angular 
}

//NOTE: I need the watcher to catch changes not done by someVeryLongFuntion()
$scope.$watch('variableThatKeepsChanging', function () {doSomething()});
```

Thank you.

Comment: then do not watch it

Comment: I need the watcher because of the build of my aplication, the question is if there is any way to stop a digest and to execute whenever you want some time after

Comment: I suggest sort the variables you are watching before you start messing with digest cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript does not run tasks in paralel, and since the angular part of an aplication is something that also runs under Javascript, then you don't have to worry about it, because the watchers won't be triggered until the end of the function that you are executing.

Read more about the Javascript event loop and the angular $digest and $apply to understand this.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope (Integration with the browser event loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put it to `$timeout` service with `0` timeout

```
$timeout(function(
    someVeryLongFunction();
), 0, false);
```

Take a look to third parameter in `$timeout` service, it shouldn't call `$apply()`, but you will need to call afterwards yourself

Answer (score 0):

in your case I feel that instead of a watcher a `$emit` or `$broadcast` would suit you better, so you have direct control when to send the event.

but yes you can unbind and rebind watchers... although toggling them is fairly uncommon and is not such a great practice

have a function to add a watcher:

```
var addWatcher = function(name){
return $scope.$watch(name...)
}
```

if you want to watcher to do something just add a callback to the watcher so it will do something;
call it with:

```
var mywatcher = addWatcher('scopeName');
```

to disable the watcher call:

```
myWatcher();
```

something like that